# Installing npm packages at lower version of node

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to install npm packages at lower version of node, since there is node 8 installed on the server and don't have the access to the server, as few packages are not compatible with node 8, so is there a way in package.json by which npm packages can be installed at lower version. Will engine property of package.json allow that

Answer (score 0):

`engines` property in `package.json` is for your whole app. Your app **CAN NOT** use multiple node versions at a time.